# ExpandableListView - android

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have a question about the expandableListView in android

I want to expand the ExpandableListView only when the user clicks on the indicator not in any other place and to remove the Expand by clicking on a button in a childview

and I want to know if it is possible to expande the list to up instead of to down ( which means that the child appears above the parent)